# Can I solve this mathematically? $({x^7}\mod33)^d\mod33=x$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can I find x or d value for

$({x^7}\mod33)^d\mod33=x$?

Or can I make at least some assumptions of range of those values?

I ask for a mathematical way because that "33" usually is a number bigger than 2^100, so going for tries isn't a solution...

Comment: the problem is that that "33" usually is a number bigger than 2^100

Comment: This does not solve your problem, but interestingly for the number $33$ and $d=3$ we have that $(x^7\mod 33)^3\mod 33 = x \mod 33$ for *all* positive integers $x$.